# Video view seeking inconsistencies

Tags: android, android-videoview, frame-rate

I have a video that I record at 60 frames per second or 30 frames per second. Now I view that video in a video view. I want the video to skip frame by frame on each skip button tap.

The issue is that the seek to method looks for nearest key frame and move to that position. So sometimes when I am skipping frames it shows inconsistent behaviour due to that.

So how can I achieve this?

This is the code I am using to seek the video view:

```
    int currentPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();

    double increment = 1000/60;

    currentPosition += Math.round(increment);

    if (videoLoader.canSeekForward()) {
           videoLoader.seekTo(currentPosition);
    }
```

So the method `videoView.getCurrentPosition()` sometimes returns wrong value.

Comment: I see that you are dividing by 60 in your increment parameter. Why not pass your method the frame rate and divide by that? Meaning, double increment = 1000/ frameRate

Comment: I can do that but that is not causing the problem.  The problem is seeking to a particular frame. I tested the code with a video that was recorded at 30fps and it still had the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by replacing video view with ExoPlayer. ExoPlayer has a method called `setSeekParameters`. Just use that method with the below parameter:

```
setSeekParameters(SeekParameters.EXACT)
```

and then the seekto method will seek to exact frames and not just the nearest key frames.